# jquery check if string starts with 1234

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

I want to check if a string has exactly 7 characters and starts with "1234". How do I do that?

I know of string.substring but am not sure if I shouold use regex or are there any other alternative. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Exactly 7 chars and starts with "1234567"? Easy! `if (str == "1234567") ...`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Simple RegExp:

```
var isMatch = /^1234...$/.test(myString);
```

Or:

```
var isMatch = myString.length == 7 && myString.indexOf("1234") == 0;
```

**Edit:** Or:

```
var isMatch = myString.length == 7 && myString.substr(0, 4) == "1234";
```

Comment: Thanks Gilly. I'll make your answer as the answer to my questions in 11 minutes. Thanks again!

Comment: `substring` and equality check is preferable to `indexOf` since it doesn't need to search all the string in case of a miss. Also, IMHO a good answer should discourage using a regex for something as simple.

Comment: @Jon - Fair enough, I've added a `.substr()` version.  But personally, I love regular expressions - so precise and tidy.

Comment: Careful, IndexOf is not Supported in IE8 Browser.

Comment: @PedroLopes - You are thinking of `Array.prototype.indexOf()`.  But, this is a string, and `String.prototype.indexOf()` has been around since at least IE4.