# jQuery - check if value starts with specfic characters

Tags: jquery

I have some validation at the moment that returns false if a user enters a value that is less than 7 characters as so:

```
        if (nextPgeNum == 3 && $('#txt-centre').val().length < 7 ) {

            alert("Invalid Cost Centre");

            return false;

        }
```

What I need to do is add further validation to the same element to return false if `#txt-centre` doesn't begin with '212'

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073510/jquery-check-if-string-starts-with-1234

Comment: Is it enough for the value to start with `212`? Or must *all* conditons be true at the same time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a string "StartsWith" another string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/how-to-check-if-a-string-startswith-another-string)

Comment: both length must be => 7 and value must start with '212'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might go with a regex like

```
if (nextPgeNum == 3 && !/^212.{4,}/.test($('#txt-centre').val())) {
    alert("Invalid Cost Centre");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest, for simplicity, using `indexOf()`:

```
if (nextPgeNum == 3 && $('#txt-centre').val().length < 7 &&  $('#txt-centre').val().indexOf('212') === 0) {

    alert("Invalid Cost Centre");

    return false;

}
```

It might be worth caching the value, since it's being accessed twice, and also removing leading/trailing white-space (with `$.trim()` or `String.prototype.trim()`):

```
var value = $.trim($('#txt-centre').val());
if (nextPgeNum == 3 && value.length < 7 &&  value.indexOf('212') === 0) {

    alert("Invalid Cost Centre");

    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (nextPgeNum == 3 && $('#txt-centre').val().length < 7 && !$('#txt-centre').val().startsWith("212")) {
```

That is basic JavaScript.

Comment: Didnt know about that function, but the support isn't great... Well thank you for teaching me something !

Comment: "The support isn't great". What do you mean by that?

Comment: Limited compatibility for [`String.prototype.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).

Comment: That it is not supported by any IE, Safarie and opera : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Browser_compatibility

Comment: They mean a lot of engines (including V8, Chrome's engine) don't have it, as it's not in the standard yet (not even ES5). ES6 will have it, and hopefully implementations will add it fairly quickly, but...

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the pointer. I just open Firebug and see what the autocompletion delivers :)

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution with good browser support is `substring`:

```
var val = $('#txt-centre').val();
if (nextPgeNum == 3 && val.length < 7 && val.substring(0, 3) !== "212") {

    alert("Invalid Cost Centre");

    return false;
}
```

I think you wanted `!==` there...