# Restrict form input in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The below code seems to work perfectly fine in Chrome but falls short on IE11.

```
<input placeholder="Username" name="uid" type="text" required="required" pattern="^(?!.*ue).*$" />
```

I want to restrict users from typing in the form anything **beginning** with ue. Currently this stops any input with ue inside it and doesn't function on IE11.

Could I possibly use jQuery to accomplish this? I am not very familiar with the limitations or functionality of jQuery.

**UPDATE:**

I ended up searching and doing some trial and error and came up with the below.

```
<input id="un" placeholder="Username" name="uid" type="text" onBlur="return userid()" value=""  required="required" />
```

Script:

```
   function userid() {
    var str = document.getElementById("un").value;
    var patt = new RegExp(/^ue.*$/);
    var res = patt.test(str);
    if (res === true) {
            alert('Do not use UE ID.');
            document.getElementById("un").focus();
            } else {}
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to achieve this. Here you can find an answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/8073527

Comment: Had a quick play around with some of those variables but couldn't get it to work. I will look into it a bit more in the morning. Stay tuned!